# Excel Find the text between the last two underscores

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula to find the text between the last two underscores in an excel cell:

i.e.

> `AAA_BBB_CCC_DDDD_E => DDDD
>
>   AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_E => EEE
>
>   AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_F_ => F
>
>   AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EE_GGGGGGGGGG => EE
>
>   AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE_FFF_GGGGGGGGGGGG_H => GGGGGGGGGGGG`

The formula i got is based on the last index of:
[EXCEL LAST INDEX OF](http://geekswithblogs.net/prash/archive/2011/11/02/excel-last-index-of.aspx)

> `=RIGHT(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",""))))-1),LEN(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",""))))-1))-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",""))))-1),"_","@",LEN(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",""))))-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"_",""))))-1),"_","")))))`

I need to make this less complicated, any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(H3,"_",REPT(" ",100)),200),100))
```

Note, if any of the segments could be longer than 50 characters, increase the 100 and 200 figures accordingly

Comment: I added Len(A1) function instead of the 100, just to make it safer, though not cleaner :P

Answer (score 2):

The solution of chris is quite neat - however, I came up with an alternative too.

```
=MID(A1,1+SEARCH("@", 
     SUBSTITUDE(A1,"_","@",LEN(A1)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUDE(A1,"_","")))),
     SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUDE(A1,"_","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUDE(A1,"_",""))))-1-
     SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUDE(A1,"_","@",LEN(A1)-1-LEN(SUBSTITUDE(A1,"_","")))))
```

Comment: Whats LÄNGE(WECHSELN(A1,"_","")))), can you tell me their names in english please?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variation.....

`=MID(A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))-1))+1,SUM(FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))-{0,1}))*{1,-1})-1)`

Comment: I like the idea of using [instance num] optional parameter in the substitute function, though i have no idea what *{1,-1} means